# Route 53 "A" record is not pointing to Ec2 elastic IP address

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I recently spun up an EC2 instance for WordPress. I also associated this instance with an Elastic IP and I can access my instance via this elastic IP address. I also purchased a domain in Route 53 and created a DNS zone. this DNS zone is having  3 records (A, NS, SOA). I configured A record to the Ec2 elastic IP address and in a few minutes, My domain is successfully linked with the Ec2 instance. and I can ping my website [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) successfully.

Here is the actual issue, I tried to connect my domain to a CloudFront CDN and it didn't work as expected I ended up doing many changes to the DNS. So finally I deleted this DNS zone and created a new DNS zone and did a fresh mapping of A record to Ec2 elastic IP. I also took care of updating 4 new name servers to my domain back.

From this point onwards, my domain ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) is not working. It's not pointing to the Ec2 domain. Every time I pined my domain, it's unavailable.

Can you please advise if I am missing anything here?

Thanks In Advance
Venk

Comment: Can you share real domain name?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The actual issue is, whenever I type [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) in google chrome it's automatically converting this into https://www.example.com and the webpage isn't available.so I changed HTTPS to only HTTP and the webpage is available now.

Thanks
Venk